# MapView and GoogleMap in the same application

Tags: android, google-maps

Can I use MapView and GoogleMap in the same application in Android?
I use API V2 for the map. My intention is I'd like to have overlay on the map for Geofencing application. But GoogleMap doesn't support well for the overlay.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you mean MapView from Android API v1 then no, you can't.

API v1 required you to extend `MapActivity` and v2 requires `FragmentActivity` (when using SupportMapFragment). You could combine Maps v1 and v2 on a single `Activity`, but only as two separate `Views`.

Anyway `GoogleMap` has a good support for overlays. There are `GroundOverlay` and `TileOverlay`. You may want to ask a new question how to achieve something with them if you have problems.